# How to CAST to decimal without rounding in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Using this SQL statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT[User].Id) AS UserTableCount, 
COUNT(QA.RequestID) AS QACount, 
QA.AssignedToUser, 
CAST((COUNT(QA.RequestID)/COUNT(DISTINCT [User].Id)) AS DECIMAL(10,4)) AS PercentOf 
FROM [User]  
JOIN [QA] ON [User].Id = [QA].RequestId 
WHERE QAStatus = 'Pink' GROUP BY [QA].AssignedToUser
```

I get these results:
[image]

How do get a 2 decimal space result that isn't rounded?

Comment: cast as decimal(10,2) ?

Comment: Sorry about the formatting not sure how to display the SQL without side scrolling.

Comment: Define rounding please, since casting or changing of precision will always lead so some deviations requiring some kind of rounding.

Comment: What column are you looking for here? And what do you expect as output?

Comment: Well, it isn't showing the full value if I do the math.  What should I use instead of cast to get the exact amount to 2 decimal places?

Comment: @SeanLange I'm dividing QACount by UserTableCount

Comment: `COUNT` will return integers, and since the division is performed with two integers, the result will be an integer. The __result__ (already an integer) will then be cast to float.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL is performing the division using integer datatypes.  Multiply one of the inputs that you are using for division by 1.00.

Ex.

```
CAST(((COUNT(QA.RequestID)*1.00)/COUNT(DISTINCT [User].Id)) AS decimal(10,2))
```

In this situation:

```
CAST((COUNT(QA.RequestID)/COUNT(DISTINCT [User].Id)) AS DECIMAL(10,4))
```

the result is not what you would hope to receive because the integer division is performed before the cast operation.

Comment: @C B that worked except now I have too many decimal places.  How do I limit it to two?

Comment: @Kyle G CAST((COUNT(QA.RequestID)*1.00)/COUNT(DISTINCT [User].Id) as decimal(10,2))

Answer (score 3):

Cast both sides of the division operator to decimal.

You are doing integer division which produces an integer result, and then converting that integer to a decimal, which is going to have zeros behind the decimal point like all good integers do.